# How can there be an enqueue event outside the function range of enqueue events?

Tags: queues, queueing-theory

I'm trying to understand Figure 1 in this theoretical description for queues: [https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~abraham/courses/Concurrency14/2(Logic)/3.Qexample.pdf](https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/%7Eabraham/courses/Concurrency14/2(Logic)/3.Qexample.pdf)

Key excerpts from the PDF:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I grasp everything except 3(c). How can a dequeue event have a preceding enqueue event which is not in the range of the gamma function? Isn't the range of the gamma function all enqueue events that correspond to a dequeue event?

Also, what's that backwards 1 symbol after the γ in 3(c)?

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1201/). For instance, this helps others with a similar question find this page via search (e.g., searching on the title of the paper/notes you are referring to). Thank you!